# Saving to a class variable

Tags: c#, silverlight, class, variables

Hi i need to save the "pri1" variable to a class variable so other methods of the same class would be able to access. 
in between these lines

"pri1.Remove(last);

foreach (string item in pri1)"

```
void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();


                string[] split1 = Regex.Split(response, "},{");
                List<string> pri1 = new List<string>(split1);
                pri1.RemoveAt(0);
                string last = pri1[pri1.Count() - 1];
                pri1.Remove(last);

                foreach (string item in pri1)
                {
                    string abc = "[{" + item + "}]";
                    byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(abc);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buf);

                    JsonArray users = (JsonArray)JsonArray.Load(ms);

                    var members = from member in users
                                  //where member["SEARCHVAL"]
                                  select member;

                    foreach (JsonObject member in members)
                    {
                        string schname = member["SEARCHVAL"];
                        string axisX = member["X"];
                        string axisY = member["Y"];
                        // Do something...
                        string jsonCoordinateString = "{'Coordinates':[{'X':" + axisX + ",'Y':" + axisY + "}]}";
                        CustomCoordinateList coordinateList = DeserializeJson<CustomCoordinateList>(jsonCoordinateString);

                        GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["MyGraphicsLayer_Primary"] as GraphicsLayer;

                        for (int i = 0; i < coordinateList.Coordinates.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Graphic graphic = new Graphic()
                            {
                                Geometry = new MapPoint(coordinateList.Coordinates[i].X, coordinateList.Coordinates[i].Y),
                                Symbol = i > 0 ? PrimarySchoolMarkerSymbol : PrimarySchoolMarkerSymbol

                            };
                            graphic.Attributes.Add("PrimarySchool", schname);
                            graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Could be this: You want to share the value of pri1, between different events when the sender of these events are the same object... thats it?

Comment: i want to save "pri1" as a class variable i need to use it in other methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [*field*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) to the class:

```
List<string> myField;
```

You can then use the field as a variable anywhere in the class.

Comment: so which part of this is known as a class variable?

Comment: @GJJ: There's no such thing as a "class variable".  You mean a field.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a field in the class that can store the `List<string>` type

```
this.VariableName = pri1;
```

If there isn't a variable in the class and you haven't defined it your self you'll need to subclass and add it.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @SLaks - your answer is exactly the same as mine just your use of terminology is better. I will admit to having assumed that this was a black box class that couldn't be changed. Edits should now reflect that error in assumption as being amended.

Comment: I believe he's asking how to make a field.

Comment: Ahh, yeah okay. I can see that.